# Recursive feature selection with cross-validation in the caret package (R)

Tags: r, cross-validation, feature-selection, caret

The *rfe* functions in the caret package allow to perform recursive feature selection (backward) with cross-validation.

It is expected that the best features selected in each fold may differ, as also stated in the caret [webpage](http://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html)

> Another complication to using resampling is that multiple lists of the
>   “best” predictors are generated at each iteration. At first this may
>   seem like a disadvantage, but it does provide a more probabilistic
>   assessment of predictor importance than a ranking based on a single
>   fixed data set. At the end of the algorithm, a consensus ranking can
>   be used to determine the best predictors to retain.

However it is not clear to me how the final "best" set of predictors is chosen in *rfe*, considering this expected heterogeneity among folds. I cannot find the procedure of the "consensus ranking" mentioned above.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the "consensus ranking" is independent of the choosing of the "best" set of predictors.  The *rfe* function finds the best predictors but as far as I know the only place to find the actual algorithm is to go through the source code.  I think the author is implying that a "consensus ranking" is up to the user to do something with the variables.  For example, running the code example at [Feature selection: Using the caret package](https://www.r-bloggers.com/feature-selection-using-the-caret-package/) and showing the results of the random forest predictors:

```
profile.1$results

  Variables  Accuracy     Kappa  AccuracySD    KappaSD
1         1 0.9968370 0.9936464 0.007392163 0.01485547
2         2 0.9968746 0.9937256 0.009326189 0.01866587
3         3 0.9963217 0.9926185 0.009537048 0.01908711
4         4 0.9971857 0.9943537 0.006409197 0.01284846
5         5 0.9968659 0.9937105 0.007209709 0.01445173
6         6 0.9977209 0.9954207 0.006048051 0.01213925
7        20 0.9954924 0.9909603 0.009642686 0.01930148

profile.2$results

 Variables  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD
1         1 0.6483312 0.2995335 0.04698551 0.09230506
2         2 0.7723877 0.5454866 0.03916581 0.07729696
3         3 0.8274992 0.6532635 0.04604503 0.09299738
4         4 0.8388603 0.6762275 0.04361517 0.08828418
5         5 0.8309978 0.6605690 0.04846354 0.09755719
6         6 0.8242424 0.6474883 0.04556598 0.09109094
7        20 0.8005472 0.6018126 0.04871103 0.09703959

profile.3$results

 Variables  Accuracy      Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD
1         1 0.3192818 0.05197699 0.05773080 0.07663863
2         2 0.3933106 0.13560101 0.05459624 0.07598374
3         3 0.4594806 0.22122750 0.05119101 0.06953943
4         4 0.6771564 0.53076000 0.12127578 0.17285038
5         5 0.6536151 0.49190799 0.07879014 0.11242260
6         6 0.6070402 0.42205418 0.07241226 0.10155747
7        20 0.5046387 0.25116903 0.05869522 0.07952462

profile.4$results

  Variables  Accuracy       Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD
1         1 0.5154641 0.036353403 0.05806695 0.11057134
2         2 0.5117129 0.032926630 0.06592773 0.12742427
3         3 0.5198731 0.046944007 0.04739288 0.09231161
4         4 0.5187570 0.045917813 0.05237265 0.10100463
5         5 0.5118155 0.032686407 0.05595381 0.10829322
6         6 0.5105693 0.032829544 0.05683679 0.10436906
7        20 0.4972180 0.007899334 0.04944846 0.08724467
```

A consensus could be calculated on the four results using accuracy or some combinations of metrics.

Comment: This was also discussed [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/487)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry i am adding an answer here as I cannot comment yet to Brian's answer (consider this a comment to that one), but the answers to this query below also deals with this.

[Find variables selected for each subset using caret feature selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103810/find-variables-selected-for-each-subset-using-caret-feature-selection/360033#360033)

In short, rfe ***seems to*** compute 1 'overall' important ranking for each predictor once using all predictors on entire dataset. (So the "Overall" column for a predictor in rfe's `$variable` output remains same for different folds.)
You can see this score in the column "Overall" by calling `$Variables`to your rfe, like below (using Max's code from link above):

```
data(BloodBrain)

x <- scale(bbbDescr[,-nearZeroVar(bbbDescr)])
x <- x[, -findCorrelation(cor(x), .8)]
x <- as.data.frame(x)

set.seed(1)
lmProfile <- rfe(x, logBBB,
             sizes = 10:20,
             rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs, 
                                     number = 15))
lmProfile$variables
```

Looking at the output, we see that when rfe selects variables for a subset size, different variables may get selected at different resampling folds.

To find out the best predictors in the required subset size (say 10-fold), rfe sums up the "Overall" importance ranking for a predictor every time it appears in a fold in the 10-fold subset. This is how they rank the predictors. ***[I have written a crude code to replicate this in the query link above.]***

The final best predictors of the subset size are the predictors with highest summed ranks. 
(At least this is how I make sense of it; I hope I am right!)